# ss --events no output on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, iproute2

I try to monitor continously TCP connections on a CentOS 7 box with the `ss` utility. If I start `ss --events` I recieve no events. Is there any trick to enable this? Or is the kernel (3.10) in CentOS 7 too old for the excersise?

Comment: Does `ss --extended` show anything?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be OK. And if I do a `watch -n 1 ss -t`, I can 'catch'/see TCP connections, only continous listing/update doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the relevant commits:

- [iproute2 commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/iproute2/iproute2.git/commit/?id=6885e3bf8efa311322b5c32936f7f6155b03a23d):

> ss: Include -E option for socket destroy events
>
> Use the IPv4/IPv6/TCP/UDP multicast groups of NETLINK_SOCK_DIAG to
> filter and display socket statistics as they are destroyed.
>
> Kernel support patch series: [24029a3603cfa633e8bc2b3fb3e48e76c497831d](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=24029a3603cfa633e8bc2b3fb3e48e76c497831d)
>
> Signed-off-by: Craig Gallek kraig@google.com

- [kernel commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=24029a3603cfa633e8bc2b3fb3e48e76c497831d)

> Merge branch 'sock_diag_destruction_events'
>
> Craig Gallek says:
>
> ====================
> Socket destruction events via netlink sock_diag
>
> This series extends the netlink sock_diag interface to broadcast
> socket information as they are being destroyed.  The current interface
> is poll based and can not be used to retreive information about
> sockets that are destroyed between poll intervals.
> [...]

This has been included in Linux kernel 4.2.

While Red Hat backports a lot of features in older kernels, from OP's question, it appears this feature isn't available in CentOS 7's kernel 3.10.